# Can a prepared statement in MySQL contain PREPARE and EXECUTE?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I wanted to know if prepared statements can be used in the following way:

```
 public static function GetCategoryItems($categoryId,$pageNum, &$rnum_pages)
    {
    $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) AS items_count
                FROM item I
                JOIN sub_category SC
                ON I.sub_category_id = SC.sub_category_id
                JOIN category C 
                ON C.category_id = SC.category_id
                WHERE (I.location = 2 OR I.location = 3)
                AND C.category_id =' . (int)$categoryId ;
        $params = array (':category_id'=>$categoryId);
        $rnum_pages = Catalog::CalculatePages($sql,$params);
        $first_item = ($pageNum - 1) * ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
            $sql =
         "PREPARE stmt_name FROM 
        'SELECT I.item_id, I.name , I.price, I.discounted_price, I.thumbnail_photo
        FROM item I
        JOIN sub_category SC
        ON I.sub_category_id = SC.sub_category_id
        JOIN category C
        ON C.category_id = SC.category_id
        WHERE C.category_id = ?
        LIMIT ?,? ' ; 

        SET @p1 = categoryId;
        SET @p2 = firstItem;
        SET @p3 = items_per_page;

        EXECUTE stmt_name USING @p1,@p2,@p3; "
        return DatabaseConnection::GetAll($sql,$params);
        }
```

I am actually getting an error :

```
 ERRNO: 256 TEXT: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: where are `categoryId`, `firstItem` and `items_per_page` coming from? Are those supposed to be PHP variables?

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use the sql interface for prepared statements instead of some api that allows the use of the binary protocol like e.g. mysqli or pdo?

Comment: Well Im just a beginner. Im just trying out things by myself and learning at the same time. I dont know anything about mysqli..

Comment: Now you've edited the question there's no prepared statement of any kind left in the code snippet.

Comment: I am sorry for that..Ive put back the prepared statements

Comment: I have modified the following line and removed the prepare and execute statement and I no longer get the error. But now i need help to figure out how to add parameters to the LIMIT clause without using prepared statements. C.category_id = SC.category_id WHERE C.category_id =' . (int)$categoryId;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the PREPARE and EXECUTE statements are 'client-side' operations that the `server-side' of the DBMS does not normally see.  This used to be a hard-and-fast rule; things are now blurred with stored procedures and the like allowing dynamic SQL.  Consequently, what you're attempting *may* be possible in MySQL, but it looks dubious (at least).

However, given that you have problems, I recommend splitting up the second chunk of SQL into two separate operations - and omit the PREPARE blurb and the EXECUTE blurb.  You will need to pass the parameters to the statement that executes the split SQL (to the execute phase of the split SQL, in fact).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try to do what you suggested. :)

Answer (score 0):

You prepare `stmt_name` but execute `stmt` - is this just a typo?

What about the `categoryId`, `firstName` and `items_per_page` - where are those coming from?

Comment: infact i was using a stored procedure which receives 3 parameters : CREATE PROCEDURE xyz(categoryId INT, firstItem INT, items_per_page INT). I was having problems using stored procedures(Refer to my previous posts). So I switched to simple sql statements. I dont know if i am using prepared statements correctly. Can anyone guide me in using them?

Answer (score 0):

In the user comments in the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), from "Brian at diamondsea":

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. ...
>
> After spending hours trying to track down why we were getting this error on a new server, after the same code ran fine on other servers, we found the problem to be an old MySQL *client* library running on our web server, and a latest-version MySQL *server* running on the database server's box.
>
> Upgraded the MySQL client on the web server to the current revision and the problem went away.

Comment: Actually the error is 
:ERRNO: 256
TEXT: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error
LOCATION: C:\xampp\htdocs\final\classes\database_connection.php, line 81, at January 11, 2010, 7:33 pm
Showing backtrace:
trigger_error("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error", "256") # line   81

I am not having unbuffered queries problem